# Cannot invoke findMax() on the array type double[] error. a method that returns the max in an array

Tags: java

I am creating a very simple method that returns the maximum value in an array on Eclipse, and I get this following error: Cannot invoke findMax() on the array type double[]

Here is the code:

```
 class themax {
private double findMax(double[] array) {
double max = array[0];
for (int index =1; index < array.length;index++) {
    if (array[index]> max) 
    {
        max = array[index];
    }
}
return max;
}

 }
 public class maxandmin2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    double[] array;
    array = new double[5];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        array[i] = Math.random()*10;
    }
    array.findMax();
}

}
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: `themax m = new themax(); m.findMax(array);`

Comment: I replaced array.findMax(); with that, and I get this error : "The method findMax(double[]) from the type themax is not visible"

Comment: oh, I think I just have to change the method to private from public, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The method `findMax` is in the `themax` class and requires that the array is passed

You can call this method by instantiating a new `themax` and then calling it.

Change your `main` to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    double[] array;
    array = new double[5];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        array[i] = Math.random()*10;
    }
    System.out.println ("The max is " + new themax().findMax(array));
}
```

**note** The `findMax` method should be `public`

Comment: Thank you! and I just did a quick fix of changing the method to public afterwards  because I got this error: "The method findMax(double[]) from the type themax is not visible"  I appreciate your help!